# Using Spring to inject different instances of a class based on instantiation hierarchy

Tags: java, spring, logging, dependency-injection, slf4j

I have a class structure along these lines:

```
public class Worker {
    private Parser parser;
    private Validator validator;
    private Feeder feeder;

    //...
}
```

`Parser`, `Validator` and `Feeder` are all interfaces with different implementing classes. These fields are instantiated within the context of the instantiation of the Worker, and are not shared among workers.

Something I want to do is to have a single instance of `org.slf4j.Logger` for each Worker, that then would be used by the parser, validator and feeder as needed. Basically, at instantiation, we want to give the Worker a name, and then have all logging use that name, like so:

```
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(workerName)
```

Ideally, I would like for a solution along these lines:

```
public class XmlParser implements Parser {
    @Autowired
    private Logger logger;

    //...
}
```

And then have the autowiring functionality of Spring Framework configured to use the same instance of Logger in all objects that belong to the same Worker. Different workers should get different Logger instances, obviously. Forcing all three interfaces `Parser`, `Validator` and `Feeder` to specify a `setLogger()`-type method seems inelegant to say the least.

How could I accomplish this task using some clever dependency injection solution?

Comment: You could also use [`LoggerFactory.getLogger(Worker.class);`](http://slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.html)

Comment: @JohanSjöberg: Several instances of Worker (with different names) would share the same Logger in that scenario. If that wasn't a requirement, we could use a solution like this: http://jgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/10/auto-injection-of-logger-into-spring.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this without too much Spring magic would be to simply create the logger in the worker like you would normally do:

```
final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("workerName");
```

and then have your worker set this logger in the different components. If your components are injected by Spring, have your worker implement [InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) and set the logger in *afterPropertiesSet()*.

If you really want to do this more dynamically, have a look at [this example](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/spring-by-example-utils-module-logger.html) where a BeanPostProcessor and reflection is used to inject the right logger.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) value for your worker. If your goal is to differentiate the logs generated by the different markers, then setting the MDC might be sufficient. If you wish to have the logs generated by the different workers go to different files, then have a
look a [SiftingAppender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) and MDCBasedDiscriminator.